# Show UIView from UIActivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiactivity

What's the best way to present a `UIView` on a `UIViewController` from inside a `UIActivity`. I tried the code below but that's not working. Aside from that there doesn't seem to be any documentation on this.

```
- (void)performActivity {
    ...
    do some stuff
    ...

    [self.activityViewController.presentingViewController.view addSubview:toast];

    [self activityDidFinish:YES];
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? You attach your toast (dialog?) to a view in the ViewController and then tell it to finish so your view is also not visible anymore.

Comment: Well, I'd like to show it in the `UIViewController` that has the share button and shows the share sheet.

Comment: Why don't you use a modalViewController to present over your current VC?

Comment: Because it's a toast, not a complete `UIViewController`. It's basically just a `UIView` with some text in it meant as a notification.

Comment: In that case. Why not use an UIAlertView? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863481/how-to-create-an-alert-box-in-iphone

Comment: Because this fits better in the design.

Comment: If design is a thing then you might as well customize the alertview to fit your tastes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331396/custom-uialertview-iphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by just retrieving the current `UIView`.

```
UIView *vc = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject];
[vc addSubview:toast];
```